# Why is smooth scroll working only after F12

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to add a smooth scroll to my webpage. When I click on **About, Projects or Contact me** links, I want it to automatically scroll to their respective section.

But its working only after I press F12(developer tools) and click on the above links

I am really confused by this behavior. What could be the issue? Why is it not working without opening dev tools?

Below is the code

index.html

```js
function smoothScroll() {
  $('#about, #projects, #contact').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 20
      },
      500
    );
    return false;
  });
}

$(smoothScroll);
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <li><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="#projects">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact Me</a></li>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <section class="portfolio">
    <div id="about">
      <h3>Full Stack Engineer</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="projects">
      <p>Some of the projects I have worked</p>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h3>Gift Savvy</h3>
          <img src="" alt="Project 1" />
          <p>This is a full stack web application</p>
        </li>

        <li>
          <h3>Money Mapper</h3>
          <img src="" alt="Project 2" />
          <p>This is an expense tracking application</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h3>Nutrition tracker</h3>
          <img src="" alt="Project 3" />
          <p>This is a calorie tracking application</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="contact">
      <a href="">Linkedin</a>
      <a href="">GitHub</a>
      <a href="">Email</a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 

</body>
```

Comment: Can you expand on "not working properly" and "not working"? Those broad phrases are _all_ you've used to describe your problem. Use more detail and some descriptive terms.

Comment: I have clearly mentioned that its working only when I press F12

Comment: And what exactly is the behaviour when you don't? Beyond "not working".

Comment: By F12 I assume you mean 'developer console' (Chrome). Can you clarify you mean it only works when developer console is open? Or do you mean closed. Or is F12 doing something else. Much better to say what you are logically doing rather than just say 'F12'

Comment: Is the page perhaps not long enough to scroll before F12? And do you have mobile device emulation?

Comment: You mean to say it works only when the page is of particular length?

Comment: If the page fits completely in the window... It won't scroll... That's obvious.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette lol nothing was obvious with this question as posted.

Comment: @Shravani if you're still struggling with this you may want to post a working sample. Developers really aren't too keen on 'not working' as a problem. When somebody at my work texts me and says "the website is down" or worse "is the website down?" it drives me NUTS. But with that said, may I suggest using the `debugger;` command or setting break points in your code to make sure that you're really getting to the expected locations. Also try a crazy offset like `top - 100` or `top + 200` to see what happens. I mention screen size and device emulation since these could possible affect behavior.

Comment: @Simon_Weaver Thanks for the reply. The web content was not sufficient enough for smooth scrolling to work.

Comment: Smooth scroll is working now after adding some more content to the web page